# Flutter - How to add items on the top of a Listview builder?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, listview, dart

I have a `Listview.builder` on my app to add player in my game. As I show in the gif here:

[image]

What I want to do is, instead of adding the player "test2" under the player "test", I want to add it on top of him... I tried the `reverse` method, but if I do that, the Listview start from the bottom of the screen...

Do you have any idea to solve this ?

Here is my code :

```dart
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: Provider.of<PlayerProvider>(context).getPlayerList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                PlayerDismissible(index),
                Divider(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  height: 0,
                )
              ],
            );
          }),
      bottomSheet: BottomPlayerBar(),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add new player to the list you can use [insert](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/List/insert.html) method on `List` to add new player as the first one in the list like..

```
Player newPlayer = Player('name');
playersList.insert(0, newPlayer);
```

Comment: I feel stupid now, I hadn't thought about this solution, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the top of a list is not efficient because it needs to shift all the remaining items of the list to the right. Just add to the list by `add()` and  get the item by reversing the index:

```
PlayerDismissible(length - index - 1)
```